# Replacing an attribute in an array exists, or adding a new attribute pair if not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to following setup:

`<input onChange={ e => this.onChange(e)} name="input_title"/>`

Which runs the following function when I input any letter:

```js
onChange(e){
            //pulling in the array to check
            const tempArray = this.state.inputField;
            //condition to check for
            const checkForExistingInput = obj => obj.name === String(e.name);
            //storing index if condition met (-1 if condition not met)
            var index=tempArray.findIndex(checkForExistingInput);

            if(index >= 0){ //if condition met set value to the input attribute
                tempArray[index].input=e.target.value;

            }else{tempArray.push({name:e.target.name, input:e.target.value});} //if condition not met, push new attribute pair

        this.setState({ inputField:tempArray }, () => {console.log(this.state.inputField)});
        }
```

However, it seems to not "find" any existing names and simply adds another item to the array:

[image]

EDIT: Thanks to the kind folks below, the problem was a naming error in my conditional: `String(e.name)` should have been `e.target.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
const checkForExistingInput = obj => obj.name === e.target.name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Its seems like you re trying to get event.target.name

Comment: Thank you very much!